# Class 'PdfConsultas' not found codeigniter4 v4.1.3

Tags: php, codeigniter-4

greetings I have a problem tells me that the class pdfquery does not work.
in the old version of CodeIgniter4 if it worked.
download through composer the fpdf make a controller with a class pdfquery that extends from fpdf and thus be able to call that class to my other controller query.
but it does not want to recognize me in this version since in another version of CodeIgniter if it worked for me that way.
I attached images I have deleted some data so that the image does not look so extensive, thank you very much.

[image: example]
[image: exaple2]
[image: example3]
[image: example4]

Comment: Please do not post code in images; copy the text into code tags instead.

Comment: So not using "namespace" and "use" in your PdfConsulta class worked in older versions of CI 4?